# Can a surjective function $f: \mathbb N\to \mathbb N $ be not injective?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Can a surjective function $f: \mathbb N\to \mathbb N $ be not injective?

Hi;
I've been breaking my head over this simple question since last night.
It's actually a small sub problem (of a simple Analysis Question) to what I'm trying to solve but essential to me solving it.

At first I thought it can not be. 
For example, say there is an infinite number of $ n \in \mathbb N $ that map to some x and an infinite number that doesn't.

But then, wouldn't the first have to be finite?

Because, for example if I were to arrange that first infinite subset on a line and say that all other terms that "hit" every other $n \in \mathbb N $ come afterwards then we'd never get to the other ones. 
Are they there?

I apologize if this doesn't make a lot of sense.

I'm quite confused by all the scenarios that I can think of. It (the feeling of wonder) makes me excited and kind of happy, but also quite helpless.

I appreciate any tip to guide my thinking in the right direction.
Cheers

Comment: Does your definition of $\mathbb N$ include $0$?

Comment: Note that the properties of surjectivity and injectivity of a function are independent of each other.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I usually don't. My textbook does though.

Comment: @ParasKhosla Thank you. I was aware of that, as I liked proving these things often before. I was really thinking in the wrong direction here, but thanks to J.W Tanner's example below I have seen some light :-)

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like sort of confusion most people go through when they first encounter this kind of stuff. But there are alot of stuff you can do with infinite sets that you can’t with finite ones. For example, when you fear that «we will never get to them», but this is untrue. In that case there are natural numbers that hit numbers other than n, and it’s not like any of these are infinitely far away, each single one of them is very much finite

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not completely, I actually looked at this yesterday. But in the way I phrased my problem. Probably yes. It's actually not complete, this is part 1 of 5. I just didn't wan the answers to all.

Comment: @JonathanHole Thank you! Your Answer is actually more or less the answer to half my homework. It relates to permutations and Series, so I wondered if I have a surjective permutation function if I can "get" all the terms into one fnite set even though they are infinite number that map to the same value to keep a series to converge. If that makes any sense. Haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Consider $n\mapsto\lfloor \frac {n+1}2 \rfloor$

Comment: Thank you so much that's a great example, I've even seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Consider the sequence of natural numbers (a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$) :

$$1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots $$

Answer (score 1):

Define $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ by $f(n)=n-1$ when $n>n_0$ and $f(n_0)=n_0$, where $n_0$ is your favourite smallest natural number.

Comment: Thank you! Great example. That's how I approached it in the beginning and got to the weird infinity fork where I took a wrong turn. :-)

Comment: Nice to be of use :)

Answer (score 1):

Take, for instance, $f(n)=1+\lvert n-2\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you! Another good example. So many! :-). I can even think of some more myself now. I was a little too stubborn in thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Yes. It's much harder to find an example when you don't believe that such an example can exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take

$$f(2n)=n$$ and

$$f(2n+1)=6n+4$$

$ f$ is surjective but

$$f(1)=4=f(8)$$
so, it is not injective.